# Check files, fix damaged and restore missing files, 14.04

Tags: 14.04, boot-repair, tty, restore, error-handling

During process of fixing login issue, sometimes various error [messages](https://itsfoss.com/wp-content/uploads/2012/06/ubuntu-12.04-apport-error.pngrity.png) has been shown in TTY and on GUI desktop, one of the last:
op
      Sorry, Ubuntu 14.04 has experienced an internal error.

```
    ExecutablePath
     /usr/sbin/cupsd
```

How to check all Ubuntu files for integrity, to fix errors authomatically, fix damaged and restore missing files?(if such was found) Is there system utility or other method for this?

Comment: There is probably no need to do it, but you can run `sudo touch /forcefsck` and reboot. Disks will be checked.

Comment: @Pilot6 Looks like maybe that's an answer

Comment: @Seth made an answer

Answer (score 1):

You can run a terminal command

```
sudo touch /forcefsck
```

This will force the system to check all disks on the next reboot.